# Можно ли вывести итератор у std::string? C++

Tags: c++, строки, итераторы

Допустим я перебираю строку через цикл с итераторами. Как мне вывести символ строки, соответствующий данной итерации цикла? std::cout << str[i] << "\n"; не работает.
Код:

```
for(auto i = str.begin(); i != str.end(); i++) {
    // здесь надо вывести символ в данной итерации цикла
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(auto i = str.begin(); i != str.end(); i++) {
    cout << *i;
}
```

Вот и всё :) Итератор - это аналог указателя, который при разыменовании с помощью `*` дает то, на что указывает.

Comment: А можно ли как-то получить интекс этого элемента в строке? Если i с оператором * дает символ, то как получить индекс?

Comment: Строго формально - `distance(str.begin(),i)`, но в данном случае сработает и `i - str.begin()`. Но индекс - вещь в общем случае (для других контейнеров) менее эффективная, чем итератор.